# How to transform Json to another Json by using Xslt and Java

Tags: java, json, xslt-3.0

I want to take input as the below Input Json and the requirement is after transformation the result should be below Output Json.

**Input Json**

```
{
   "members": [
      {
         "name": "Molecule Man",
         "age": 29,
         "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to convert the above JSON to look like this:

**Output Json**

```
{
   "resourceType": "Test",
   "type": {
      "name": "Member"
   },
   "displayName": "Molecule Man",
   "attributes": {
      "test": [
         {
            "value": "29"
         }
      ],
      "testing": [
         {
            "value": "Dan Jukes"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried with transformation in which the output json is same as input json. I did it for fetching some values from the input json. But now the requirement is the input json will be converted into different json.

Comment: How about starting writing some XSLT 3? You have asked a couple of questions on that topic already but never show any attempt to solve your current problem with XSLT 3. Try to practice creating/manipulating XDM maps and arrays with XPath 3.1 and/or XSLT 3, don't expect us to write the code for you for any new requirement.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I understand  I tried but didn't get any solution. But I can assure you this is the last question on this topic. Please help me this time. Please give me any idea.

Comment: You have seen examples using e.g. `map { 'resourceType' : 'test' }` with XPath 3.1 to construct a map and `<xsl:map><xsl:map-entry key="'resourceType'" select="'test'"/></xsl:map>`.  So start working with the answers you have received, the documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-map-entry and show us some part of how you tried to solve the latest question on your own, then explain which part failed with which error message.